# Unable to open Zip file downloaded using Django

Tags: python, django, zip

I am converting a directory and all its contents into a zip file and downloading it but when I try to open the downloaded zip file I am getting the error:-

> C:\Users\user1\Downloads\directory1.zip: Unexpected end of archive

Here is my function for zipping and downloading the directory as a zip file in Django:-

```
def download(request):
        body = request.body
        #fetching directory name from request body
        directory = body['directory']
        #dir_name contains path of the directory to be converted into zip 
        dir_name =  BASE_DIR + '\\downloads\\' +"\\{0}".format(directory)
        #zip_file_name is the full path of the zip file which will contain the directory as a zip
        zip_file_name = dir + '.zip'

        ###Creating Zip File
        zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_name, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
        path = dir_name
        ziph = zipf
        # ziph is zipfile handle
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for file in files:
                ziph.write(os.path.join(root, file), 
                        os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, file), 
                                        os.path.join(path, '..')))
        zipf.close()
        #Define the full file path
        filepath = zip_file_name
        #filename is the name to be given to the downloaded zip file
        filename = directory + '.zip'
        
        ###Download section 
        # Open the zip file for reading content
        path = open(filepath, 'r', errors="ignore")
        # Set the mime type
        mime_type, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(filepath)
        # Set the return value of the HttpResponse
        response = HttpResponse(path, content_type=mime_type)
        # Set the HTTP header for sending to browser
        response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % filename
        # Return the response value
        return response
```

If I try to set `path = open(filepath, 'r', encoding="cp437")`, I get this error

> The archive is either in unknown format or damaged

Without the parameters `encoding` and `errors`, it does not get even downloaded and throws this error:-

> 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 267: character maps
> to

What should be the actual encoding and other parameters that should be used so that the zip file gets downloaded correctly and can be opened?